# Can't load resource even tho it linked up correctly

Tags: html, css

I have this html file called register.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Register</title>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom css Style -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

  <h1 class="hello">Hello</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

The css file is in the same folder as the html file.
This is the style.css file.

```css
.hello {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

When I run the code it says that the resource style.css can not be loaded.
When I open the raw file using safari it work but when I use the flask server it doesn't work.
Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: if it is in the same dir, you could try `href="file://./style.css"`. But you should know it won't work if you deploy it

Comment: If you are using Flask, try putting your CSS file inside a folder named `static`, and then call it like this: `<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/style.css') }}" />`

Comment: Yes thank you that's works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style.css` most probably is being resolved by the browser to something like `http://your-server.com/style.css` (implying you are viewing it from `index.html` from the root of your server), so if your file is not in the same directory or the web server is not configured to serve such files, the browser won't load it.

Comment: It's in the same dir

Answer (score 1):

May be it's a path error. style.css are not available on that specific path.You can check complete error by inspect element on your browser console or in application logs too.

Comment: Looking at the error on the chrome inspector. It says error occurred trying loading the resource. I've started from scratch to see if that will but it still not working.